# I want my android webview to launch a specific URL in the native browser

Tags: android, mobile, webview, android-webview

I have fully implemented a webview, equipped with a custom webviewclient and its delegates (shouldInterceptRequest and onLoadResource), but now I want to open the native browser when the user clicks a link to a specific url and block the webview from navigating to it.

I have implemented "shouldInterceptRequest" (for custom behavior with sites on my internal network), and when the user clicks the link to this specific site I want to open in the native browser, I see the request being caught by "shouldInterceptRequest". Now I don't know how to prevent this URL from loading, since this delegate expects a WebResourceResponse. And if I return null, the webview will begin loading the URL.

Comment: When user clicks a tag with target="_blank" or window.open is called, [onCreateWindow method of WebChromeClient class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onCreateWindow) is called. How about override onCreateWindow method?

Answer (score 0):

Override `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view,WebResourceRequest request)` to return true and launch the native browser.

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading does not get fired when I click this link (javascript href). Only shouldInterceptRequest and onLoadResource get fired.